# Which one is the best approach for validating emails

Tags: ecmascript-6

I just have a quick question; which one is the best approach between joi and regular expressions for validation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers here (including this one) will be very bias as your question is very subjective.

I will try to give you to be as objective as possible.

First, let us review what JOI and Regular Expressions are:

JOI is a javascript only library that does **schema-validation of javascript objects**. It uses (according to its github page example) regular expressions.

Regular expression is common across language (with some variations may be) which **can be used (among its usecases) to validate strings**.

If you are writing a web UI and wants to validate the data filled in by the user, JOI is purpose built (because it can take care of the whole objects).

If you just want to check e-mails are in correct form, JOI will be an overkill. In this specific instance, you can live with just a regular expression.

**Subjective part:** There is a certain school (group) of software engineering community who does not like regular expression due to readability issues. I am one of them. If you want just e-mail validation, I'd recommend you write a validator yourselve (to check if it includes '@' sign ... and a valid domain name follows '@' etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Very simple validation and then send an email with a validate email link. Trying to validate email address beyond @ followed by . you will get it wrong unless you read the whole email spec and have a ridiculously complicated regex.